# Obtain id of current element in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items that are organized in an alphabetical order on a page. I would like to create a fixed element at the side of the page that shows, which letter section you are currently scrolling by.

For example, if you are scrolling past items starting with the letter 'D', the fixed div will show 'D'. I have been trying to create this with jQuery, but have been finding it tricky.

Each section has the class 'card-container' and an 'id' corresponding to the current letter.

ie.

```html
<div id="a" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
<div id="b" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
<div id="c" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
...
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

EDIT

So far I have this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var letters = $('.card-container');

  letters.each(function(section) {
    if($(this).position().top <= winTop) {
      console.log($(this).context.id);
      $('.letter-show h3').text($(this).context.id);
    }
  });
});
```

So this seems to work, but I feel like it's not very performant. Any suggestions to improve on this?

Comment: you can get the position of the mouse point and relate that to the position of div OR, some arbitrary position that you define.

Comment: Well, you can rely on the offset position of every elements as well as the current scroll position to determine which element should be targeted.

Comment: There's not much you can do to improve your code - a few millisecond gain at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment: There's not much you can do to improve your code - a few millisecond gain at most. Stuff like minimizing the DOM lookups and breaking the loop when the right element is found, dropping jQuery, etc... But I doubt you'd notice a difference even on the slowest machine you can find around.

```js
var letters = $('.card-container');
var letterShow = $('.letter-show h3');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();      
  letters.each(function(section) {
    if($(this).position().top <= winTop) {
      letterShow.text($(this).context.id);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card-container {height: 300px;border-top: 1px solid}
.letter-show {position: fixed}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="letter-show"><h3></h3></div>
<div id="a" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
<div id="b" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
<div id="c" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
<div id="d" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
<div id="e" class="card-container">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: @steveax Honestly, I don't believe there would be a visible difference. Maybe if there were thousands/millions of card-containers... It might be interesting to test it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what did the trick:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var letters = $('.card-container');

  letters.each(function(section) {
    if($(this).position().top <= winTop) {
      $('.letter-show h3').text($(this).context.id);
    }
  });
});
```